# Using "sheet.appendRow([ file.getUrl()]" is working, but how would I make it show a pretty name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The Title explains it all.  Well, at least I hope it does...
Thank you in advance for any help.
'
     function onOpen() {
          var folder = DocsList.getFolder("My Folder");
          var contents = folder.getFiles();
          var file;
          var data;

```
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.clearContents();



      sheet.appendRow(["Link", "Name", "Type", "ID"]);
      for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
        file = contents[i];
        var value1,value2,value3;
        if (file.getFileType()==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {
          var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
          value1 = otherSheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
          value2 = otherSheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
          value3 = otherSheet.getRange('B3').getValue();


        } else {
          value1 = null; value2 = null; value3 = null; value4 = null;
        }
        sheet.appendRow([ file.getUrl(),value1,value2,value3,value4]);
      }
    };'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display the URL as a hyperlink.  If this is the case, you can use the range setFormula() method.

Here is some sample code that gets a file URL and builds a spreadsheet formula using the HYPERLINK function:

```
function addURL() {
  var url = DocsList.getAllFiles()[0].getUrl(),
      cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell(),
      hyperlinkName = 'Whatever!',
      formula = '=HYPERLINK("' + url +'", "' + hyperlinkName + '")';  
  cell.setFormula(formula);
}
```

It will ask you for authorisation to run the function but it works.

Try this:

```
function addHyperlink() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      url = DocsList.getAllFiles()[0].getUrl(),
      hyperlinkName = 'Whatever!',
      formula = '=HYPERLINK("' + url +'", "' + hyperlinkName + '")';
  sh.appendRow([formula]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping there was some syntax within the "sheet" class.  Becuase the entire line is: sheet.appendRow([ file.getUrl(),value1,value2,value3]), so as you can see there are other conciderations.

Comment: THANKS! Very close, and it is my fault.  I did not explain the whole context.  I need the urls of sheets I returned in a folder. Best that I just show you the whole formula.  I will Edit my question with the entire script.